# ggplot: dynamically set coord_cardesian() limits based on input data

Tags: ggplot2

I've been trying to implement a function that lets a user easily plot different versions based on specified variables of interest or subsets of data without having to replicate the code or hardcode the settings. I've put all relevant plotting functions into a list inside a 'params' function that I add to the respective ggplot call. This works fine except for defining the `coord_cartesian()` limits dynamically as a function of the data. I don't understand how to call the data from within `coord_cartesian()` without having to specify any dataframe or column names.

Minimally reproducible example:

```
plot.params<-function(){
  list(
    geom_boxplot(outlier.color = 'transparent')
  )
}  

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=var1, y=var2, group=var1)) +
  plot.params()
```

[image: boxplots]

```
plot.params<-function(){
  list(
    geom_boxplot(outlier.color = 'transparent'),
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, max(as.data.frame(df%>%group_by(var1)%>%summarise(upper=quantile(var2, 0.75)+IQR(var2)))[,'upper'])))
  )
} 

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=var1, y=var2, group=var1)) +
  plot.params()
```

[image: boxplots with axis limits]

However, this above approach always uses the entire dataset and doesn't adjust when subsetting within the ggplot() call. It also uses hardcoded dataframe and column names, which I'd really prefer to avoid doing.

These following approaches don't work and return various errors.

```
plot.params<-function(){
  list(
    geom_boxplot(outlier.color = 'transparent'),
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, max(as.data.frame(.data%>%group_by(.group)%>%summarise(upper=quantile(.y, 0.75)+IQR(.y)))[,'upper'])))
  )
}  

plot.params<-function(){
  list(
    geom_boxplot(outlier.color = 'transparent'),
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, max(as.data.frame(.data%>%group_by(group)%>%summarise(upper=quantile(y, 0.75)+IQR(y)))[,'upper'])))
  )
}
```